# neo4J error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j

I am trying to run the following code.

CALL gds.graph.create.cypher(
'my-cypher-graph',
'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN id(n) AS id',
'MATCH (a:Person)-[:LIKES]->(b:Person) RETURN id(a) AS source, id(b) AS target'
)
YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount, createMillis;

But I got this error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed

Failed to invoke procedure gds.graph.create.cypher: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Node-Query returned no nodes
I am running Neo4J 4.1.0

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the db had 0 nodes. The gds.graph.create.cypher function actually does not CREATE the nodes.
So this question is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**#Check for appropriate version for neo4j and GDS library from that git file**

https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science

**# first create a node and relationship**

create (:Person{name:"Oliver Stone"})-[:LIKE]->(:Person{name:"Karan Kajrolkar"})

#Then try to create native projection

CALL gds.graph.create(
'my-native-graph',
'Person',
'LIKE'
)
YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount, createMillis;

**#O/P**

graphName|nodeCount|relationshipCount|createMillis|

"my-native-graph"|2 |1|51|